# flask_appbuilder - python-ldap library is not installed

Tags: python, flask, ldap, apache-superset, flask-appbuilder

I'm trying to use flask_appbuilder to integrate Apache-superset with LDAP.

I put the configuration in /venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/superset/config.py

```
#from flask_appbuilder.security.manager import AUTH_DB,AUTH_LDAP

#AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_LDAP
#AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION = True
#AUTH_LDAP_SERVER = "ldap://X.X.X.X ldap://X.X.X.X"
#AUTH_LDAP_SEARCH = "DC=XX,XX"
#AUTH_LDAP_BIND_USER = "XX\\%s"
#AUTH_LDAP_UID_FIELD = "sAMAccountName"
```

started superset, there is no error about ldap library, but when I try to login through web I get the error

> ERROR:flask_appbuilder.security.manager:python-ldap library is not installed.

Then I started the troubleshooting:

```
(venv) [root@apache-superset venv]# pip freeze | grep ldap ldap3==2.9
pyldap @ file:///home/btsiklauri/pyldap-3.0.0.post1-py3-none-any.whl
python-ldap==3.3.1 python3-ldap==0.9.8.4


(venv) [root@apache-superset venv]# rpm -qa | grep ldap
python3-ldap3-2.8.1-2.el8.noarch
openldap-2.4.46-15.el8.x86_64
openldap-devel-2.4.46-15.el8.x86_64
```

I tried to change the **import** line in the file /venvlib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/security/manager.py:

```
    # Ensure python-ldap is installed
    try:
        import ldap
    except ImportError:
        log.error("python-ldap library is not installed")
        return None
```

I tried to install (ldap3, python-ldap, python3-ldap, python-ldap3, pyldap), but with no success.

What else can I check?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and it turned out to be a missing dependency of `python-ldap` (In my case it was `pyasn1`, `pyasn1-modules`).

I found this out when I ran `import ldap` in a python shell and got `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyasn1_modules'`

Answer (score -1):

Try `pip install python-ldap` to install the correct library. Projects don't install every library because that would lead to loads of unused code.

Comment: OP said they tried to install `python-ldap` among other libraries and that didn't solve the problem.